# Unable to set options with PHP WkHtmlToPdf

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I try to use WkHtmlToPdf with Php using Michael Härtl wrapper called PHP WkHtmlToPdf but i can't declare any options.

This code works fine

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf('http://www.example.com');
$pdf->binary ='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
if (!$pdf->send('pres.pdf')) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
}
```

Now if I try to set options I get a blank page

```
$globaloptions = array(
    'no-outline',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'orientation' => 'Landscape',
    'enable-javascript' => true

);

use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

$pdf = new Pdf('http://www.example.com');
$pdf->setOptions($globaloptions);
$pdf->binary ='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf';
if (!$pdf->send('pres.pdf')) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
}
```

Comment: Try $pdf->setOptions($globaloptions);
$pdf->addPage('http://example.com');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$globaloptions = array(
'no-outline',
'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
'orientation' => 'Landscape',
'enable-javascript');
```

Comment: Thanks, 3 hours I was searching.